# is there any other way to except optional.ifpresent() to check if value populated or not

Tags: java, xml, spring, validation

currently xml node in request file coming in, the value 01/22/2020 has to be populated. we have some new test cases where they are sending in blank and it throws an exception. so need to change this logic to accept null as well.

what else way is there except optional class? to keep code clean.

```
        if(!date.equalsIgnoreCase("Today")){
```

Thanks this one worked. I just had to put another check for empty nulls.

```
 if (date != null && !date.equalsIgnoreCase("Today"))
```

shoutout to user85421.

Comment: it threw an exception unparseable date : "" after trying.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional check can be reversed - instead of:

```
if(!date.equalsIgnoreCase("Today")){
```

use

```
if(!"Today".equalsIgnoreCase(date)){
```

"Today" is not null so it will never throw a NullPointerException.

However, since the requirement changed, the `String date` parameter should be changed to `Optional<String> date`.  This makes the code self-documenting, without having to look at the implementation.  But depending on how the XML is parsed, this might not be feasible.

Also, consider using `LocalDate` internally, and convert to `Date` if the return type cannot be changed to `LocalDate`.